# How to run a Python code on AWS EC2 and write a csv file from the server to my local machine?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a python program that ultimately writes a csv file using pandas:

```
df.to_csv(r'path\file.csv)
```

I was able to upload the files to the server via FileZilla and was also able to run the program on the EC2 server normally. However, I would now like to export a csv file to my local machine, but I don't know how to.

Do I have to write the csv file directly to a cloud drive (e.g. google drive via Pydrive)? What would be the easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not want to expose your computer to the dangers of the Internet. Therefore, it is better for your computer to 'pull' the data down, rather than allowing something on the Internet to 'push' something to it.

You could send the data to Amazon S3 or, if you are using a cloud-based storage service like Google Drive or Dropbox, use their SDK to upload the file to their storage.